# Am I at a dead end in my linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I got several persons in my DB. Some of them are listed in a "OverviewSortOrders" table, but not all of them.
When I collect all of my persons in my linq Im joining the OverviewSortOrders but persons hwo not is listed in that table isn't in my result of course.
But I want those people even if they are in that table or not.

```
from...
join...
join..
 join sorting in db.OverviewSortOrders on person.PersonRef equals sorting.PersonRef into moso
 from subsorting in moso.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where subsorting.UserRef == rp.UserRef
    select new
                        {
    SortOrder = (subsorting == null ? int.MaxValue : subsorting.SortOrder),
    ...
    ...
```

If the persons aint in the table it will not get true this: "where subsorting.UserRef == rp.UserRef".
But even if they are in the table or not I whant to collect them to my list. But on those hwo have a sortOrder I will set its value.

The question is:
Is i possible to solve this in the linq and give a value to the people that have a value and a maxValue to the other people that aint in the table. Or do I need to break that part out from the linq that I pasted above. And collect all of my persons (even if they are in the "OverviewSortOrders" table or not) and later give them the value?

Comment: You don't have to do everything in one massive query.  You could get the two sets of people, with much simpler queries, then combine them and sort them.

Comment: This line is causing your problem `where subsorting.UserRef == rp.UserRef` - if subsorting doesn't exist and is null, then the equals clause won't be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
from subsorting in moso.DefaultIfEmpty()
where subsorting.UserRef == rp.UserRef
```

...to:

```
from subsorting in (
  from ss in moso
  where ss.UserRef == rp.UserRef
  select ss
  ).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: That worked! :) Is it pure hard working to learn the linq or have you guys been practicing it allot? Im not talking specific on this problem. Of course I need some more time with it to develop my knowledge. But do you have any suggestions to be a better "linq:er"? ;)

Comment: Like everything, it has a learning curve. Play around with it for a bit and you will soon learn your way around it... :)   (Yeah, I have used it since 2007, so I have had a chance to practice... :) )

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a left outer join. You already do that with `DefaultIfEmpty` but the `where` condition that follows reverts that.

Try changing it like that:

```
where subsorting == null || subsorting.UserRef == rp.UserRef
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work :/ I had my hope on this hehe. I dont know if it generate an left outer join.